# Accessing mediaDevices.getUserMedia in InAppBrowser / Cordova

Tags: cordova, android-webview, inappbrowser

I'm building a Cordova hybrid app and trying to access the local camera & microphone using javascript mediaDevices.getUserMedia which is in a page on my website. I am opening it via InAppBrowser but access to the camera & microphone is not working.
The InappBorwser code is,

```
open_url = 'https://example.com/index.php';
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(open_url, "_blank", "location=no,zoom=no,EnableViewPortScale=no,toolbar=no");
```

I have set the following Android user permissions in AndoidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

but I am seeing a permissions problem 'DOMException: Permission denied' when the following code is run.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
```

I have tried running InAPPBrowser with '_system' and this works but it pops the browser window outside of the app which is not what I want. I have also tried setting app permissions manually in Android to no avail. If i run 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });' locally in the app, access seems to be ok but I require to bring the code in via browsing.

Comment: seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550329/allowed-camera-and-audio-in-inappbrowser-on-cordova-android and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74342021/open-camera-fron-inappbrowser-in-cordova.

Comment: Have you tried the answers provided in the second link? i.e. https connection rather than http? and the solution made in this PR? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/968

Comment: Thanks Mister_CK. It's over https and I gave the info in the link a test but it has not worked.